# xml sort and count not working correct

Tags: xml, xslt

I seem to have a problem in either my xml file or xsl file.  Here is what is supposed to happen 
The XMl file contains votes when it is displayed it is supposed to sort and order the results by rank # of votes and by percent and display the results. It all looks right except for the percent of votes is way off. 
What am I doing wrong?

XMl code

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="os.xsl" ?> 

<poll>
<ballot id="b1">

   <os>Windows Server 2003 Standard</os>
   <os>Suse Linux</os>
</ballot>
<ballot id="b2">
     <os>Windows Server 2003 Standard</os>
       <os>Ubuntu Linux</os>
       </ballot>
<ballot id="b3">

</ballot>
<ballot id="b4">
    <os>Windows Server 2003 Standard</os>
    <os>Debin Linux</os>
</ballot>
<ballot id="b5">
   <os>Suse Linux</os>
   <os>Windows Server 2003 Standard</os>
   <os>Debin Linux</os>
</ballot>
<ballot id="b6">
   <os>Suse Linux</os>
   <os>Ubuntu Linux</os>
   <os>Windows Server 2008 Standard</os>
   <os>Debin Linux</os>
</ballot>
<ballot id="b7">
   <os>Debin Linux</os>
   <os>Ubuntu Linux</os>
      <os>Debin Linux</os>
</ballot>
<ballot id="b8">
   <os>Windows Server 2008 Standard</os>
   <os>Debin Linux</os>
    <os>Ubuntu Linux</os>
    <os>Suse Linux</os>
     <os>Debin Linux</os>
    </ballot>
</poll>
```

xsl code starts below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!--

-->


        <xsl:key name="oss" match="os" use="."/> 

    <xsl:variable name="single-os" select="//os[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('oss', .))]/."/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Top Customer Server OS</title>
        <link href="os.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Top Customer Server OS </h2>
        <table border="0" width="550">
        <tr><td colspan="4">Number of the Ballots: <xsl:value-of select="count(poll/ballot)"/></td></tr>

        <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>os</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
        <th>%</th>
        </tr>


    <xsl:for-each select="$single-os">

    <xsl:sort select="count(key('oss', current()))" order="descending" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:variable select="count(key('oss', current()))" name="votes" />
        <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.</td>
        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        </td>
        <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="$votes" /></td>
        <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="format-number($votes div count(//ballot), '#.00%')" /></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 10 = 0">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing the percentage, you are diving the number of votes for an **os** by the total number of **ballot** elements:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($votes div count(//ballot), '#.00%')" />
```

What you should be doing is dividing the number of votes for an **os** by the total number of votes for all **os** elements

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($votes div count(//os), '#.00%')"/>
```

This should give you the result you need.